How to go to previous screen with one-to-one relationship with react native?
I have react native expo web app. And I try to go to the previous screen. The problem I am facing is that there is one main screen. And a subcategory screen with has a one-to-one relationship. Fore example you have mammals(main screen) and then you have dogs --> bulldogs --> English bulldog.
And the user is on bulldogs and what to go back to dogs. Then the

goBack()

doesn't work. Because then the user goes back to the mainscreen(mammals).
So I try it like this:
import { useNavigation, useNavigationState } from "@react-navigation/native";

const routes = useNavigationState((state) => state.routes);
const previousRoute = routes.length > 1 ? routes[routes.length - 2] : null;
const previousParams = previousRoute ? previousRoute.params : null;
const previousId = previousParams ? previousParams.id : null; 

and the back button code:
<Button
    title="go back"
    onPress={() => {
    navigation.navigate("dieren");
    console.log(previousId);
    previousId && <Text>Previous ID: {previousId}</Text>;
}}>
    back
</Button>

But the output of previousId is

null

But this doesn't work. The user goes anyway back to mainscreen. And not the previous screen.
The api call for the subcategories looks like:
export const fetchSubCategoryData = async (id) => {
    const token = await retrieveToken();
    try {
        if (token) {
            const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/categories/${id}/`, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            });
            //console.log(response);
            return await response.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error(token);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        Error("can't retrieve data");
    }
};


And the url of a subcategory looks:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories/13/

The output of the api call is this:
{
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Papegaaiachtigen - Psittaciformes",        
        "animals": [],
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "Papegaaien van de Oude Wereld - Psittaculidae",
                "description": "",
                "images": "https://dier.blob.core.windows.net/media/media/photos/categories/Papegaaien_van_de_Oude_Wereld_EgDy7Sb.jpg",
                "subcategories": [],
                "animals": [
                    33,
                    35,
                    34,
                    38,
                    19
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "name": "Papegaaien van Afrika en de Nieuwe Wereld - Psittacidae",
                "description": "",
                "images": "https://dier.blob.core.windows.net/media/media/photos/categories/Papegaaien_van_Afrika_en_de_Nieuwe_Wereld_Dfw542h_RDc4P7j.jpg",
                "subcategories": [],
                "animals": [
                    31,
                    45,
                    41,
                    29,
                    43,
                    30,
                    18,
                    46,
                    17,
                    42,
                    37,
                    13,
                    16,
                    12,
                    15,
                    14,
                    32
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 22,
                "name": "Kaketoes - Cacatuidae",
                "description": "",
                "images": "https://dier.blob.core.windows.net/media/media/photos/categories/302299828_6pxpbCt.jpg",
                "subcategories": [],
                "animals": [
                    40,
                    36,
                    39,
                    44
                ]
            }
        ],
        "category": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories/19/"
    },
}


In this example you have papegaaien(main category)(13) - an then sub categories: Papegaaien van de Oude Wereld(16), Papegaaien van Afrika en de Nieuwe Wereld(17).
and normally you go from top to bottom: id13 tot (id16, id17), but now a user want to go from the screen with the (ids16, id17) to the main category 13. So from bottom to top.
So for example a user is on url:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories/16/

and want to go back to url:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories/13/

Question: How to go to previous screen within the same component: SubCategoryScreen?
